# Creating a txt file from Excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, macros

I am using the below code to create a .txt file from an excel sheet. However it seems to produce another column at the start of the file and I cannot figure out why. Any Help would be appreciated.

A9:M287 are all filled with content also so it is not a hidden blank column.

```
Sub StoretoTXT()

Dim answer As Integer

answer = MsgBox("Have all the required fields been filled and are correct?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Data Check")
If answer = vbYes Then
    Dim c As Range, r As Range
    Dim output As String

    For Each r In Range("A9:M287").Rows
        For Each c In r.Cells
            output = output & vbTab & c.Value
        Next c
        output = output & vbNewLine
    Next r

    Open "C:\Test\Desktop" & Format(Now(), "YYYYMMDDHHMMSS") & "Test.txt" For Output As #1
    Print #1, output
    Close

    MsgBox "File has now been created. Excel will now close"
    ActiveWorkbook.Close False
Else
    'do nothing
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You are putting a `vbTab` in before adding `c.value`.  This results in `output` *always* starting with `vbTab`.  You will need to put in a check to see if it is the first cell and if so don't put in a tab.

Comment: You realize there's a way to save directly as a Tab-Delimited file, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be easier to just use the `SaveAs` method to create a tab-delimited file. Since you're looking only for specific range, first copy that range to a new workbook, and then save as `xlText`:

```
Sub SaveAsTabDelimited()
Dim rng as Range
Dim newWB as Workbook
Set rng = Range("A9:M287")
Set newWB = Workbooks.Add
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
With newWB
    Do While .Worksheets.Count > 1
        .Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count).Delete
    Loop
End With

rng.Copy newWB.Worksheets(1).Range("A1")
'## Modify path to file output in the next line:
newWB.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Debug\tab-delimited.txt", FileFormat:= _
    xlText, CreateBackup:=False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
newWB.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you I didn't actually realise I could do it that way